# Stop / Hide GTMSessionFetcher Logs SwiftUI

Tags: xcode, firebase, swiftui, analytics, firebase-analytics

is there way to hide and stop print in the Xcode console below types of logs.

> GTMSessionFetcher invoking fetch callbacks, data {length = 2270, bytes = 0x7b227265 73756c74 223a7b22 72657375 ... 52696465 73227d7d }, error (null)

**ScreenShot**

[image: ScreenShot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Follow below steps:-**

1. Open Xcode and find GTMSessionFetcher folder
2. Select GTMSessionFetcher Class
3. Comment the GTMSessionFetcher Log Debug line.

**Please Check the attached screenshot.**

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I can't edit the dependency - does anyone know how to make it editable?