# Table View not displaying fetched data from Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having difficulties trying to display my users data in a Table View.

I think the code is correct, I'm just not displaying it correctly. I've tried so many days now that I'm resorting to a kind stranger pointing me out where I went wrong...

Here are some screenshots:

This is my Database on Firebase, it has a very simple structure.
[image: Database Structure 1]

[image: Database Structure 2]

[image: App View with the Table View]

Here is my code for the view:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class InserisciViewController: UIViewController {
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var labelTutorialInserisci: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonEntrate: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonUscite: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    var transactions: [Transaction] = []
    
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
    
    // Define a struct to represent a transaction
    struct Transaction {
        let userId: String
        let name: String
        let type: TransactionType
        let amount: Double
        let date: Date
    }

    // Define an enum to represent the transaction type
    enum TransactionType {
        case positive
        case negative
    }
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        title = K.Generic_Text.scrittaInserisci
        navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
        
        labelTutorialInserisci.text = K.App_Text.tutorialInserisci
        
        
        // First, create a reference to the "utenti" collection
        let utentiCollectionRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("utenti")

        // Then, query the "positive" and "negative" collections for each user
        utentiCollectionRef.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error fetching documents: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }

            var transactions: [Transaction] = []

            for _ in snapshot!.documents {
                // Get the user's ID
                let userId = self.user!.uid

                
                // Query the "positive" collection for the last entry by date
                let positiveCollectionRef = utentiCollectionRef.document(self.user!.uid).collection("transactions").document("transactions").collection("positive")
                positiveCollectionRef.order(by: "data", descending: true).limit(to: 1).getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("Error fetching documents: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        return
                    }

                    // Parse the data and add it to the transactions array
                    for document in snapshot!.documents {
                        let data = document.data()
                        let name = data["name"] as! String
                        let number = data["number"] as! Double
                        let date = data["data"] as! Timestamp
                        transactions.append(Transaction(userId: userId, name: name, type: .positive, amount: number, date: date.dateValue()))
                    }
                }

                // Query the "negative" collection for the last entry by date
                let negativeCollectionRef = utentiCollectionRef.document(self.user!.uid).collection("transactions").document("transactions").collection("negative")
                negativeCollectionRef.order(by: "data", descending: true).limit(to: 1).getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("Error fetching documents: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        return
                    }

                    // Parse the data and add it to the transactions array
                    for document in snapshot!.documents {
                        let data = document.data()
                        let name = data["name"] as! String
                        let number = data["number"] as! Double
                        let date = data["data"] as! Timestamp
                        transactions.append(Transaction(userId: userId, name: name, type: .negative, amount: number, date: date.dateValue()))
                    }
                }
            }

            // After all queries have completed, sort the transactions array by date and display it in a table view
            transactions.sort { $0.date > $1.date }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }
    
}
```

[image: Logs]

Answer (score 0):

There are a few serious issues in the code.

The most significant one is that you have **two** `transactions` arrays. The main property on the top level of the class which drives the table view (presumably) will never be populated.

The second issue is that you reload the table view a long time (in terms of computer speed) before the first request sends its data.

You need `DispatchGroup` to be notified when both **asynchronous**  positive/negative tasks have finished and delete the local `transactions` variable.

I'm pretty sure that `Firebase` supports `async/await` which gets rid of  `DispatchGroup` but I'm not so familiar with this library.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class InserisciViewController: UIViewController {
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var labelTutorialInserisci: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonEntrate: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonUscite: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    var transactions: [Transaction] = []
    
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
    
    // Define a struct to represent a transaction
    struct Transaction {
        let userId: String
        let name: String
        let type: TransactionType
        let amount: Double
        let date: Date
    }

    // Define an enum to represent the transaction type
    enum TransactionType {
        case positive
        case negative
    }
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        title = K.Generic_Text.scrittaInserisci
        navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
        
        labelTutorialInserisci.text = K.App_Text.tutorialInserisci
        
        
        // First, create a reference to the "utenti" collection
        let utentiCollectionRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("utenti")

        let group = DispatchGroup()
        
        // Then, query the "positive" and "negative" collections for each user
        utentiCollectionRef.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error fetching documents: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }

            for _ in snapshot!.documents {
                // Get the user's ID
                let userId = self.user!.uid
                
                
                // Query the "positive" collection for the last entry by date
                let positiveCollectionRef = utentiCollectionRef.document(self.user!.uid).collection("transactions").document("transactions").collection("positive")
                group.enter()
                positiveCollectionRef.order(by: "data", descending: true).limit(to: 1).getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
                    defer{group.leave()}
                    if let error = error {
                        print("Error fetching documents: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        return
                    }
                    
                    // Parse the data and add it to the transactions array
                    for document in snapshot!.documents {
                        let data = document.data()
                        let name = data["name"] as! String
                        let number = data["number"] as! Double
                        let date = data["data"] as! Timestamp
                        self.transactions.append(Transaction(userId: userId, name: name, type: .positive, amount: number, date: date.dateValue()))
                    }
                }
                
                // Query the "negative" collection for the last entry by date
                let negativeCollectionRef = utentiCollectionRef.document(self.user!.uid).collection("transactions").document("transactions").collection("negative")
                group.enter()
                negativeCollectionRef.order(by: "data", descending: true).limit(to: 1).getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
                    defer{group.leave()}
                    if let error = error {
                        print("Error fetching documents: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        return
                    }
                    
                    // Parse the data and add it to the transactions array
                    for document in snapshot!.documents {
                        let data = document.data()
                        let name = data["name"] as! String
                        let number = data["number"] as! Double
                        let date = data["data"] as! Timestamp
                        self.transactions.append(Transaction(userId: userId, name: name, type: .negative, amount: number, date: date.dateValue()))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        group.notify(queue: .main) {
            // After all queries have completed, sort the transactions array by date and display it in a table view
            self.transactions.sort { $0.date > $1.date }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error, I updated the question with the logs

Comment: The error(s) cannot be caused by my changes especially not "Unknown class in Storyboard"

Comment: Ok thanks :) , but do you know what could be the cause?

Comment: I doubt that all lines are errors. The first line points to a class `viewcontroller` without corresponding Swift or Objective-C class. Is the data displayed?

Comment: That line of the log is actually not a result of this view.

These two are:
2023-04-27 17:07:27.321651+0200 My Personal Budget[79614:1759181] GTMSessionFetcher invoking fetch callbacks, data {length = 1419, bytes = 0x7b0a2020 226b696e 64223a20 22696465 ... 33363030 220a7d0a }, error (null)
2023-04-27 17:07:27.710686+0200 My Personal Budget[79614:1759181] GTMSessionFetcher invoking fetch callbacks, data {length = 648, bytes = 0x7b0a2020 226b696e 64223a20 22696465 ... 7d0a2020 5d0a7d0a }, error (null)

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69688905/stop-hide-gtmsessionfetcher-logs-swiftui) is something about GTMSessionFetcher.

Comment: I don't need to hide the logs... Why would I, they help me identify the problems...